# How can I use WebBrowser to display XML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I have some XML that I need to show. It would be perfect if I could use WebBrowser to display xml just like IE does. It has syntax highlighting and nodes can collapse.

This works:

```
WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)this.GetTemplateChild("PART_Browser");
browser.NavigateToString("<html>hello</html>");
```

However this doesn't:

```
WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)this.GetTemplateChild("PART_Browser");
browser.NavigateToString("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ArrayOfResultSet xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Search.Shared.Results"><ResultSet><Name>Bing</Name>...</xml>");
```

How can I get WebBrowser to display XML like Internet Explorer?

Comment: this should help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XMLBrowser.aspx

Comment: @cichy you should post your comment as answer, because its what Steven is looking for.

Comment: @cichy It doesn't work for WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK then, here it is:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XMLBrowser.aspx
Didnt want to post it as answer because there's not much of knowledge of mine, just a url i had in bookmarks ;)

Comment: This solution doesn'twork for WPF. The best one is here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71069/A-Simple-WPF-XML-Document-Viewer-Control

Answer (score 1):

Well I had a similar requirement of yours, so I wrote a control that supports 
 1. displaying of xml stored in a string(with IE like styling), 
 2. edit it on fly and
 3. validate against a schema

Here is the link http://nnish.com/2012/04/12/wpf-xml-browser-control/

Let me know if that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need for WPF http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71069/A-Simple-WPF-XML-Document-Viewer-Control